# Android NDK build doesn't install shared libraries to libs

Tags: android-ndk, makefile

My app has a native part that calls native Opencv's Camera libraries.

My only problem is that the NDK-build doesn't automatically copy the necessary libnative_camera****.so into `libs` folder.

I have to manually copy them each time I make a change in JNI's code (which happens to be about 3 time each minute), which is fine but annoying.

And this happens only with the native_camera libraries, `opencv_java` is automatically copied.

Here's my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED


OPENCV_PATH := /home/tran/signs/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native

include $(OPENCV_PATH)/jni/OpenCV.mk
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := cameramodule.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog
LOCAL_MODULE     := cameramodule
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

How can I change it to tell the NDK-build to do the copy and paste for me?

**UPDATE:**

I compile my app using Eclipse.
Here's the structure of the project:

```
PROJECT
   |
   |
   |---src
   |---gen
   |---res
   |---jni
   |---libs
   |---lib (Someone suggest this folder but I can see it has no use)
   |... files and temporary folders
```

** UPDATE **

`ndk-build` log:

```
rm -f project/libs/armeabi/lib*.so project/libs/armeabi-v7a/lib*.so project/libs/mips/lib*.so project/libs/x86/lib*.so
rm -f project/libs/armeabi/gdbserver project/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver project/libs/mips/gdbserver project/libs/x86/gdbserver
rm -f project/libs/armeabi/gdb.setup project/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup project/libs/mips/gdb.setup project/libs/x86/gdb.setup

Install        : libcameramoduleged.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libcameramodule.so
install -p project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libcameramodule.so project/libs/armeabi-v7a/libcameramodule.so
ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  project/libs/armeabi-v7a/libcameramodule.so
Install        : libopencv_java.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
install -p project/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so project/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  project/libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
```

Comment: Do you build the app inside Eclipse including the JNI part? Please disclose the directory structure of your project.

Comment: Can you post a log of `ndk-build V=1`?

Comment: @AlexCohn Hi, I've included the log. As you can see, no camera libraries are installed.

Comment: What is libnative.so? It's not mentioned in your `Android.mk`

Comment: @AlexCohn `native` is `cameramodule`. :D

Comment: so, it's OK now, isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [non-system libraries in linker flags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24669518/non-system-libraries-in-linker-flags)

Answer (score 0):

Move the build shared library to the top of Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  := cameramodule.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_LDLIBS     += -lGLESv1_CM -ldl -llog
LOCAL_MODULE     := cameramodule
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

OPENCV_PATH := /home/tran/signs/OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk/sdk/native
include $(OPENCV_PATH)/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Comment: But I need `include $(OPENCV_PATH)/jni/OpenCV.mk` declared before building the module, because I use opencv's libraries that is defined in `OpenCV.mk`

Comment: I did, it didn't compile due to the fact that opencv.mk must not come after the library that uses it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. But there is no mention of libnative in your Android.mk. That's strange.

Comment: Hi, libnative == libcameramodule, I thought `native` is not a very self-explanatory name so I changed it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NDK_APP_OUT and direct it to whatever directory you would like the library to reside.