# non-system libraries in linker flags

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I have a fully working app employing some C++ and OpenCV. It compiles and runs successfully. Right now I am just trying to tidy my code and make changes to remove all warnings at compile time. But there is one warning I don't understand. It appears to be a problem with my android.mk.

When I compile, the console output is as follows:

```
06:58:21 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Motion ****
"C:\\android-ndk-r9c\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: mixed_sample <= cpp_part.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libmixed_sample.so
C:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: hidden symbol '__aeabi_atexit' in C:/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a(atexit_arm.o) is referenced by DSO c:/opencv-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

06:58:24 Build Finished (took 2s.515ms)
```

My android.mk is as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# compile with profiling
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -pg

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

 OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off 
 OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on 
 OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED

include c:\opencv-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := mixed_sample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := cpp_part.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl -lz

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android-ndk-profiler

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android-ndk-profiler)
```

I can't even work out where the "-lopencv_java" linker flag comes from, it doesn't appear anywhere in android.mk.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** In response to Alex Cohn's question. If I add "$(info ==$(OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES)==)" in the line preceding "include $(CLEAR_VARS)" then the console reports the following:

```
08:39:34 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project Motion ****
"C:\\android-ndk-r9c\\ndk-build.cmd" all 
====
Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mixed_sample: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lopencv_java    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: mixed_sample <= cpp_part.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libmixed_sample.so
C:/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: warning: hidden symbol '__aeabi_atexit' in C:/android-ndk-r9c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a(atexit_arm.o) is referenced by DSO c:/opencv-2.4.8-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libmixed_sample.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libmixed_sample.so

08:39:36 Build Finished (took 2s.564ms)
```

Comment: please add line `$(info ==$(OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES)==)` before `include`, and post what it prints when you run `ndk-build`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you `include` OpenCV.mk, you must make sure that `$(OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES)` is equal **on**. You have the line `OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on` in your `Android.mk` file, but for some reason it did not work. Without digging into all possible (and impossible) problems, an easy way to fix the problem is to write

```
override OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
```

in your `Android.mk`; another - to run

```
ndk-build OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES=on
```

from command line.